# Skype for business Move-CsUser command prompts for sign in after moving 10-15 users and doesn't accept the credential

Tags: powershell, office365, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to move bulk users(900+) from SfB On-Premise to SfB-Online using Move-CsUser PowerShell Cmdlet. Below is the code snippet:

```
$INP = Get-Content -Path <txt file path>

$SESSION = New-CsOnlineSession
Import-PsSession $SESSION -AllowClobber

foreach($USER in $INP)
{
Move-CsUser -Identity $USER -Target 'sipfed.online.lync.com' -ProxyPool 'ProxyPool_FQDN' -UseOAuth -Confirm:$False
}
```

It works fine for 15-20 users and moves them successfully to SfBOnline however, after that it prompts for Office admin credentials again saying "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again" and doesn't accept the credential anymore. Keeps prompting the same.

NOTE:

- I have followed all the possibilities from Technet with no luck.
- Disabled MFA from the global admin Office account - No luck.
- Tried using -UserList parameter to move bulk users - Same issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think that you should try with stored credential $cred=get-credential at the top of your script and then add -credential at the end of your "Move-CsUser" command

Comment: @PowerCat - Thanks for the response :) 
Tried that as well. Using get-credential it connects to SfB Online successfully but the Move-CsUser doesn't work, not even for a single user.

Comment: You can try and set a timer to do 60 second sleep per user and it will do it.